# WSO2 IS Generate a Metadata partner file

Tags: wso2, weblogic11g, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to use Oracle Weblogic server and add WSO2 IS as SAML 2.0 Web Single Sign-on Identity Provider Partner

however to acheive this i need to generate a metadata partner file or use the one from WSO2 IS.

how can i retrieve this information from WSO2 IS or at least generate on myself?

i used the example seen here:

```
http://tanyamadurapperuma.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/configure-wso2-identity-server-saml2.html
```

however weblogic is saying it is unable to parse the XML,

```
 Error Unable to parse XML
 Error Create operation failed - no partner created.?
```

Answer (score 0):

I as i know content in the blog is correct...  And you can use the meta data file which in there. According to the error, it may be an issue with XML file.. I guess XML file in the blog has missed the Capital letters of the XML element. Could you try out by making them capital letters. Or else following

`<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" validUntil="2023-09-23T06:57:15.396Z">
 <md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
 <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
 <ds:KeyInfo>
 <ds:X509Data>
 <ds:X509Certificate>MIICNTCCAZ6gAwIBAgIES343gjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE
 CAwCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAcMDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxDTALBgNVBAoMBFdTTzIxEjAQBgNVBAMMCWxv
 Y2FsaG9zdDAeFw0xMDAyMTkwNzAyMjZaFw0zNTAyMTMwNzAyMjZaMFUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQsw
 CQYDVQQIDAJDQTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzENMAsGA1UECgwEV1NPMjESMBAGA1UE
 AwwJbG9jYWxob3N0MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUp/oV1vWc8/TkQSiAvTou
 sMzOM4asB2iltr2QKozni5aVFu818MpOLZIr8LMnTzWllJvvaA5RAAdpbECb+48FjbBe0hseUdN5
 HpwvnH/DW8ZccGvk53I6Orq7hLCv1ZHtuOCokghz/ATrhyPq+QktMfXnRS4HrKGJTzxaCcU7OQID
 AQABoxIwEDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBPAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAW5wPR7cr1LAdq+IrR44i
 QlRG5ITCZXY9hI0PygLP2rHANh+PYfTmxbuOnykNGyhM6FjFLbW2uZHQTY1jMrPprjOrmyK5sjJR
 O4d1DeGHT/YnIjs9JogRKv4XHECwLtIVdAbIdWHEtVZJyMSktcyysFcvuhPQK8Qc/E/Wq8uHSCo=
 </ds:X509Certificate>
 </ds:X509Data>
 </ds:KeyInfo>
 </md:KeyDescriptor>
 <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
 Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"
 ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
 <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
 Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
 <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
 Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
 </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>`

Comment: still no luck, the error i am getting in the weblogic logs is:

Cannot find the declaration of element 'md:entitydescriptor'. at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318) at

Comment: So still you are using "md:entitydescriptor" Could you please make it as capital letters? Did you also try like that?

Comment: it is capitals, the weblogic server doesnt take that into account, got it working anyway for some reason it didnt like the attribute validUntil="2023-09-23T06:57:15.396Z"

Comment: So you got this working?  By changing above attribute? or any?